# CSS: In Safari, the shadow of a tooltip remains

Tags: javascript, css, ios, reactjs, safari

I have a group of 3 buttons, and for each button, I have a specific tooltip with messages. Everything works perfectly on Windows when the tooltip is active and when it is not active. But on iOS, specifically on Safari, when the tooltip is active and then inactive, a shadow in the shape of the tooltip remains. See in the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTFuJ.jpg)

I've tried some properties with -webkit- but they didn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: use active selector of css to reset the shadow when tooltip is no more active,

if that dont work try this: `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

Comment: @AfzalK. That sounds like an interesting and possibly little known answer - may I suggest writing it up as an answer to the post for future readers to search for?

Comment: @traktor oh no, i dont think its needed, that is just a small thing, thats only of possibility

Comment: There could be all sorts of factors at play here, it would be best if you could include your css and html for the tooltip for more targeted help. For example, are you hiding the tooltip with `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

some possible solutions. When tooltip is inactive, it will have no transition effects and will disappear
eg:

```
.tooltip {
  transition: visibility 0s linear;
}

.tooltip.active {
  transition: visibility 0s linear, opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.tooltip.inactive {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  // you can try with all these or just one

}
```

you can also try adding the CSS `overflow: hidden;` to the tooltip or `pointer-events: none;`

it is possible that there may be other factors at play that could prevent these from working.